# Template function with 32-bit/64-bit integer overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

The actual function `bar` is supposed to read from file, where data is written in exactly 4 bytes or 8 bytes (`unsigned int` - `DWORD` or `DWORD64`)

```
void bar(DWORD64&);
void bar(DWORD&);

template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
    bar(out);
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    foo(a); // Caller doesn't care
}
```

Since the caller can pass any integer type (`int`, `LONG`, `DWORD`, `LONGLONG` or anything) - I want a technique so that `foo` may make a call to 32-bit `bar` or 64-bit `bar`.

In short, it would be like:

```
template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
       if(sizeof(out)==sizeof(DWORD))  // 32-bit
       {
             DWORD data;
             bar(data); // call DWORD version
             out = (IntType)data; // Ignore truncation etc.
       }
       else
       { 
             DWORD64 data;
             bar(data); // call DWORD64 version
             out = (IntType)data; // Ignore truncation etc.
       }
 }
```

Obviously, I want the "**if**" part to be resolved at compile time. `std::enable_if` or something?

Comment: Maybe you should be using *specialization* instead?

Comment: have you considered sfinae?

Comment: @W.F. Yes, I considered SFINAE, but cannot make it work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, How specialization may help?

Comment: Why don't you just use overloading and call `bar` directly?

Comment: `int a; bar(a);` won't compile. If I overload for `int`, I need to overload for `unsinged int`, then `DWORD`, `LONG`...

Comment: By the way, you know there are more integer types than the 32 and 64 bit signed/unsigned types? How about `short`? How about `char`? How about types being compiler extensions? There are a few corner-cases that needs to be handled as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Valid concern. However, all `<=4` bytes integers are 32-bit, for the problem in hand. Hence, even a `bool` read with 32-bit overload is valid (let it truncate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `std::conditional` to only differ for `sizeof(DWORD)` and `sizeof(DWORD64)` (since you want to support more than just those 2 types):

```
template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
  typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(IntType) == sizeof(DWORD), DWORD, DWORD64>::type RetType;
  RetType data;
  bar(data);
  out = static_cast<IntType>(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. For me, all 32-bit and less bit integers are DWORD. All 64-bit integers are DWORD64. So, I just need to replace `==` with `<=` :)

Answer (score 7):

Soltuion 1: SFINAE and `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename IntType, typename std::enable_if<sizeof(IntType) == 4>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
    DWORD arg = out;
    bar(arg);
    out = arg;
}

template<typename IntType, typename std::enable_if<sizeof(IntType) == 8>::type* = nullptr>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
    DWORD64 arg = out;
    bar(arg);
    out = arg;
}
```

Soltuion 2: Delegate-to-class and partial specialisation:

```
template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
    foo_helper<IntType>::call(out);
}

template <class IntType, std::size_t Size = sizeof(IntType)>
struct foo_helper;

template <class IntType>
struct foo_helper<IntType, 4>
{
  static void call(IntType &out)
  {
    DWORD arg = out;
    bar(arg);
    out = arg;
  }
};

template <class IntType>
struct foo_helper<IntType, 8>
{
  static void call(IntType &out)
  {
    DWORD64 arg = out;
    bar(arg);
    out = arg;
  }
};
```

Both solutions can be flavoured with `static_cast` added to taste, particularly around assignment to/from `arg`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::conditional` to choose the type:

```
template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out){
    using dword_t = typename std::conditional<sizeof(IntType) == sizeof(DWORD), DWORD, DWORD64>::type;
    dword_t data;
    bar(data);
    out = (IntType)data;
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GqARPe2HuEvNJZrZ)

---

Come C++17 you could use `constexpr if`, but I'm not sure if this approach is actually more readable:

```
template<typename IntType>
void foo(IntType& out)
{
       if constexpr(sizeof(out)==sizeof(DWORD))  // 32-bit
       {
             DWORD data;
             bar(data); // call DWORD version
             out = (IntType)data; // Ignore truncation etc.
       }
       else
       {
             DWORD64 data;
             bar(data); // call DWORD64 version
             out = (IntType)data; // Ignore truncation etc.
       }
 }
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QMrxjZUPSmgakKMR)

Answer (score 0):

The question is, if you passed a `int16_t`, do you want to sign-extend, zero-fill, or error?

IMO the correct thing to do is error, so here a solution with template specializations:

```
template <typename IntType>
void foo ( IntType * out ) = delete;

template <>
void foo ( uint64_t * out ) { bar ( * (DWORD64 *) out ); }

template <>
void foo ( int64_t * out ) { bar ( * (DWORD64 *) out ); }

template <>
void foo ( uint32_t * out ) { bar ( * (DWORD *) out ); }

template <>
void foo ( int32_t * out ) { bar ( * (DWORD *) out ); }
```

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants. They want to accept everything, but have it call the appropriately-sized overload of `bar`.

Comment: @Angew OK, I've added overloads for signed ints of the appropriate size.  However, it is simply irresponsible to enable any other overload.  Although the OP's original code seem to say that a uint16_t will be promoted to a uint64_t, he didn't say it in his explanation of the problem, so it's likely to be wrong.

Comment: @user2079303 Uhh, if you used a uint16, then the substitution failures against all four specializations are indeed not error; and the substitution against the unspecialized form is not an error either.  The error is forced upon it by `=delete`.

Comment: @KevinZ Indeed, I'm probably the one who's confused about SFINAE :)

Comment: There are no SFINAE here. BTW, prefer overload to specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 You don't have to have `enable_if` to SFINAE.  Also, while I agree that overload is in general better than specialization, but we are passing integers that autoconvert here.  In this situation, specialization is better than overload.

Comment: @KevinZ: Which **S**ubstitution **F**ailure you do which **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror ? I agree that `enable_if` is not the only way to have SFINAE, but here it is not the case. I don't get your point about specialization is better here.

Comment: BTW, `bar ( (DWORD64) out );` is invalid as temporary doesn't bound to non-const reference.